# Lightbox include images via URL

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have a site using URL rewrite so I have to reference resources directly rather than via a relative URL. I normally do this by appending the site url to the start of the href.

Example:

```
<script src="<?php echo SITE_URL ?>lightbox/js/lightbox.js"></script>
```

The problem is that inside lightbox.js the images are loaded relatively:

```
function LightboxOptions() {
  this.fileLoadingImage = 'images/loading.gif';
  this.fileCloseImage = 'images/close.png';
  this.resizeDuration = 700;
  this.fadeDuration = 500;
  this.labelImage = "Image";
  this.labelOf = "of";
}
```

I realise I could just do this:

```
 this.fileLoadingImage = 'http://www.example.com/images/loading.gif';
```

but it does not fit in well with my idea of abstracting the resources from their context. I want it so if I modify the site URL in my config file it will be shown in the lightbox.js file as well. I have no knowledge of Javascript so this is frustrating me.

Something more acceptable would be:

```
 this.fileLoadingImage = site_url + '/images/loading.gif';
```

Where site_url reflects the current url as per config.php. How can I get the SITE_URL constant to the javascript file?

Comment: I would initialize my lightbox script in the ondocumentready of my page and pass relevant options to the initialization, e.g. `initLightbox({baseurl:<?php echo json_encode($site_url) ?>});` (edited: using json_encode() to add quotes and escape slashes)

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a [virtual host](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_hosting), point it to your project folder that contains index.php (your public folder), then change all references to absolute (i..e `this.fileLoadingImage = '/images/loading.gif'`).

I believe this is what many frameworks do.

In the past, if I needed an ad hoc php-generated javascript variable, I would put it directly in a new `<script>` tag, in my scripts.php file:

```
<script src ="/js/jquery.js"></script>
...
<script>
  var SITE_URL = <?php echo $site_url; ?>;
</script>
```

though I'm not sure that's a very good practice.

Comment: Would that var SITE_URL be available in the lightbox.js file after it has been included? Is the variable registered in a global scope or something?

Comment: Yep, that's right. Would be available to lightbox.js as long as this script was 'included' before lightbox (i.e. put `<script src="/js/lightbox.js"></script` on the line after this one). Does that make sense?